# Optimization with bilinear constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, bilinear-form

> Let $ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_{+} $ be non-negative and $ Y, B, C \in \mathbb{S}_{+} $ a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrices. $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries. Solve
>
> $$ \begin{align}
> & \max_{a, Y} ~ a \\
> & s.t. \\
> & a \cdot {\rm{Tr}} (BY) - {\rm{Tr}} (CY) + a \cdot b \leq 0 \\
> & {\rm{Tr}} (DY) \leq c \\
> & Y \succcurlyeq 0 \\
> & a \geq 0
> \end{align}$$

**Additional information:**

To the best of knowledge the first constraint is bilinear and I wonder whether there is a smarter way of handling this constraint. Thus far, I have found two solutions, which are the following:

1. Alternate optimization: Find a feasible $ a $ and then optimize for $ Y $. Then, fix $ Y $ to optimize $ a $. And continue doing this sequentially.
2. First-order Taylor approximation: Linearize the fisrt constraint and solve the new problem for a number of iterations.

These two approaches require me to iterate over several instances. Can we do better? Thank you!

**Update:**
I have found this previous post ([Optimization problem with quadratic objective and a bilinear constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489475/optimization-problem-with-quadratic-objective-and-a-bilinear-constraint)), where the unknown parameters of a bilinear constraint are put together in a matrix. Can the first constraint in my problem be transformed in the same manner? Any hints would be great!
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} 
Y & 0 \\ 
0^T & a
\end{bmatrix} 
\succcurlyeq 0
$$

Comment: Since $a \ge 0$ perhaps you can factor $a$ out and solve the problem with $a = 0$ and $a >0$ separately?

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure if I understand your idea. $a$ and $Y$ are not known, how can I factor $a$ out?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: Notation could be improved. Having both $a$ and $A$ is not great. Having both $a$ and $\rm a$ is confusing. Given parameters from the first letters of the Latin alphabet. Unknowns from the last letters.

Comment: I have corrected the problem with /rm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quasi-convex in that it is convex for every fixed $a$ and the feasible set decreases for increasing $a$. Hence it can be solved by bisection in $a$

Example code on bisection to explain strategy
https://yalmip.github.io/example/decayrate/

If you use MATLAB/YALMIP, you can do it very easily using built-in functionality (here using mosek as SDP solver)

```
A = randn(5);A = A*A';
C = randn(5);C = C*C';
D = randn(5);
Y = sdpvar(5);
sdpvar a
b = 1;c = 1;
Model = [a*trace(A*Y) - trace(C*Y) + a*b <= 0, Y >= 0, trace(D*Y) <= c];
bisection(Model,-a,sdpsettings('solver','mosek'))
```

I belive the problem is ill-posed though (unless $D$ has certain structure relative to $A$ and $C$) which allows $Y$ to grow arbitrarily large

Comment: Johan, thank you for your reply. Yes, $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative values. I have not tried using bisection because this method would have required me to find two good initial points where the optimal solution should lie. Thus, instead I decided to linearize and initialize $a$ with 0. I think, I will give it a try with the bisection method and see how it performs. On the other hand, do you think that linearizing is silly (given that $a$ is a non-negative real value)?

Comment: Finding initial values for the bracketing is trivial, YALMIP does also that automatically (simply increase $a$  quickly until infeasible, and you have the starting interval). With a linearization strategy, you will have to add line-searches etc, and a proof that you actually converge to the globally optimal solution. Bisection is simple and you have guaranteed quick convergence.

Comment: thank you. Where can I find a convergence proof for these two methods: bisection and linearization

Comment: Bisection is trivial and classical, you half the search-space in every iteration, hence if your initial gap betweeen upper and lower bound is $U-L$, you will arrive at a desired tolerance $\delta$ in $\log_2((U-L)/\delta)$ iterations. Proving convergence of a linearization strategy (if possible) depends on your overall algorithm (line-search, backtracking etc etc)

Comment: I see!. Thank you for the details.

Comment: I have implemented the bisection method and it performs better than linearization. I would appreciate a clarification regarding your statements. If I fix $ a $, then by definition on convexity I realize that the equality holds. Then, the function is linear on $ Y $ (when $a$ is fixed) and linear in $a$ for a given $ Y $. My first question is whether bilinearity is a particular instance of quasi-convexity (or maybe my understanding of bilinearity is wrong.) My second question is how can I realize that "the feasible set decreases for increasing a" and why this is relevant. Thank you

Comment: It's a very special case of bilinearity. Bilinear in general does not imply quasi-convexity. If you make $a$ larger, you decrease the right-hand side $-ab$ thus making the feasible set smaller, at the same time you multiply with the non-negative term $\text{Tr}{BY}$ making that term larger, which also decreases the feasible set

Comment: or simply see it as $a(TrBY + b) \leq TrCY$. Both sides are positive. If you are the border of feasibility of feasibility and thus have equality, if you would increase $a$ you would become infeasible, hence the feasible set is decreasing in increasing $a$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.